# How can I make titles on LaTex

Tags: titles

I'm just a beginner Brazilian student here, I just started messing with this and I don't know how to make a title

Comment: it helps if you show what you tried, but in most document classes `\title{something}\author{Enzo} \maketitle` will do something.

Comment: please don't use external links (many people will not follow them, and the question is archived here for ever and the link will probably break, it is better to add a document as a code section in the question)

Comment: ok, sorry, i'm new here

Comment: no harm done, just a comment to help for when you post your next question:-)

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 1):

For next time, it helps if you show what you tried, but in most document classes

```
\title{something}
\author{Enzo}
\maketitle
```

will do something